# How can I extend a concrete step without repouring?

Tags: concrete, stairs, composite

Two rooms in my house are connected with a set of concrete steps (one tread). As built, the ledge for the first step is inline with the wall framing.

[image: stair ledge]

This means that when I add drywall the finished door frame will extend 5/8" over the ledge. I would like to double-rock this wall so now I'm looking at 1-1/4" overhang.The finish floor will likely be tile or perhaps something like a rubber gym mat.

I would like to add material to extend the top step by 1-1/4" but I don't want to break and repour the steps.

I'm thinking of getting a solid plastic board (like decking maybe?) And trimming it down to fit. Then glue + tapcon into the slab to hold it.

[image: flush with framing]

I have measured and the resulting tread depth will be 11-1/4" (currently 12-1/2")

How might I accomplish this?

Comment: I would get a 1-1/2” thick x the tread height board. Hard wood would be best for wood and screw it to the concrete, a thin pice of concrete will probably crack quite easily. Even a soft wood fur will last if you use a metal corner. You could then stain the wood to match the door.

Comment: what is the finished flooring material for the two rooms?

Comment: What is the height differential between the two floors.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger added detail. The higher room is tile, the lower room will likely be either tile or a rubber "gym-mat" like finish.

Comment: @Kris the height difference is two steps.

Comment: Two steps? Are the two steps pictured? What is the height difference between the two floors in inches?

Comment: @Kris the steps are pictured. The riser height is 6" so the total difference is 12". Can you help me understand why that's relevant?

Comment: I asked about the total height difference because if one step would be sufficient for the difference I’d bring the upper floor level through the doorway and over the tread.  Making a single step down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the thin little "fake bricks" (brick veneer) for this very purpose. It looks like it was supposed to be that way. The only trouble I had was when my kids were younger, they tended to "bang" their boot toes on those bricks a lot going in and eventually one cracked. But it was easy to replace.

Comment: concrete pavers could be used in that way  too.

Comment: How did you attach them? Concrete adhesive?

Comment: I used mortar. You could use concrete adhesive though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd find a tile or stone that you would be happy putting as treads/risers on the small concrete steps.

I'd try to find something that is 1" thick (maybe a concrete paver). Then I'd use LFT thinset and tile the riser to get the first riser flush with the interior sub floor(before finish floor), I'd top that riser with your tile finished floor.  The seconds riser would need to have a thinner tread on top (either of the tile to match the higher room or something to match the riser you just installed).  The sides of the concrete stair case would show the old stair to new riser transition so probably mdf board cut to the stair profile, painted and attached to the sides of the small staircase.